# Primefaces:chart doesn't show up on ajax dynamic creation

Tags: primefaces

I have a problem with chart not showing up on update, but it shows if i refresh page.

```
  <p:panel id="main">
      <p:commandbutton action="Somebeckbean"> 
      <p:panel id="something">
           <p:datatable rendered="#{mainController.tableRender}">   
           </p:datatable> 
      </p:panel>
      <p:panel id="keywordsBar">          
          <p:chart  type="bar"  rendered="#{mainController.keywordsBar}"
          model="#{mainController.horizontalBarModel}" style="height:300px;width:100%;" styleClass="center"/>   

      </p:panel>  
 </p:panel>
```

When i click button i populate data table and barchart, i set rendered to true and i update main panel.

My datatable gets rendered and it shows up but barchart is not showing up and it renderes to this.

```
</div>
     <script id="mainForm:j_idt109_s" type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         PrimeFaces.cw('Chart','widget_mainForm_j_idt109' {id:'mainForm:j_idt109',type:'bar',data:[[[9,1],[2,2],[2,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[1,8],[1,9],[1,10],[1,11],[1,12],[1,13],[1,14],[1,15]]],title:"Keyword's occurrences",legendPosition:"e",axes:{xaxis: {label:"Occurrences",min:0,max:10,renderer:$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,tickOptions:{angle:"0"}},yaxis: {label:"Keywords",renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,tickOptions:{angle:"0"}}},series:[{label:'null'}],ticks:["","Croatia","Zagreb","Accommodations","Attractions","Car Hire","Flights","Hotels","Hrvatska","News","Travel information","Zagreb City News","Zagreb Hotels","cities","city"],orientation:"horizontal",stackSeries:true,datatip:true},'charts');});
    </script>
</div>
```

I am picking up this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LinearAxisRenderer' of undefined(anonymous function) @ (program):1bI.Callbacks.i @

If i refresh page, bar is shown.
Thx

Comment: Where/how do you update you datatable and chart  components?

Comment: On commandbutton, i update whol main panel. Tried it with backbean update result is the same.

Comment: But your chart is inside the keywordsBar Panel? So it wont get updated...

Comment: So how come datatable inside some panel is updated? And why is after update barchart rendered with code shown in problem above? If i refresh page bar i shown and no ajax call or update is being made? I think updating is not the problem, something about how chart is created that i em missing :)

Comment: Sorry, your code formatting made it seems like keywordsBar was not inside the main panel. I made a edit to make it more readable. Of course the update was not the problem here, but i'm glad you found your solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39856)

It is primefaces official response for this problem.

Just add these lines in page.

```
<h:outputScript name="charts/charts.js" library="primefaces" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="charts/charts.css" library="primefaces" />
```

Comment: Next time please be way more specific in your question and mcve code example. You left out important parts of code and therefor it it was hard see that this was the issue